# shortcut keys not working for PyCharm

Tags: centos6

I have installed VirtualBox -> Centos6.8 -> PyCharm.

The shortcut keys like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or any other is not working for PyCharm. When i press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> then Centos settings window in invoked.

How can i change the key mapping?

Comment: might help https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/keymap.html

Comment: @yklsga i tried it. still no result.

Comment: Are you facing this problem only for pycharm or everything?

Comment: just with PyCharm

Answer (score 0):

All I would like to say is that the solution is simple:

Turn off **Vim Emulation** in the **Tools** menu

Comment: This answer is suitable as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: thnks. will take care from next time.